# EXT4 file, read and write inside ext4

Tags: ext4, chmod

I'm trying to modify .apk file inside ext4 file. I used **mount** to mount ext4 file and **chmod** to gain write permissions. If I mount, chmod, dont make anything else, chmod back to original permiossions, unmount - everything is fine, file is almost exactly the same. BUT when I do some changes, ext4 is completly different.
What I did - mount, chmod, delete .apk, put exactly same .apk, chmod back, unmount - ext4 file is different. What could be cause? Or its normal behaviour?

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? `ext4` is not a file. It is a kind of format for disk partition. Copy all the commands and their output from the terminal and paste then directly into your question. Then format the pasted text as `code` by using the {_} icon above [the edit window](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1440031/edit).

Comment: ext4 is a journaling file system. Deleting a file in it and then copying a copy of the deleted file back should leave traces in the journal, thus your file which holds the filesystem is going to be changed. Your question is a bit vague since it's missing the commands you use to do all that. What does it mean when you say `ext4 is completly different`?